# Get result from another activity titanium module

Tags: android, android-activity, module, titanium, appcelerator

I am facing a critical issue to develop an android module in Appcelerator Studio.

I am developing a module using a third party module that module works on bluetooth.
That third party module accepts activity object and start another activity..everything is working fine but i am not able to get result from another activity in titanium module.

I tried onResult, onActivityResult method but i am not able to get these methods invoked.

A simple example:
I have application A installed in my device and i want to to get result from that app in my module class.That third party library provides you access to invoke activity but that accepts only activity object and i am passing TiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity() as activity reference to return result on titanium module.

I am able to invoke installed app activity but the only problem is that i am not able to get result in onResult Or onActivityResult method.

Please help me to implement a process to get result from invoked Activity.
Same thing is working fine in native android.

I implemented interface TiActivityResultHandler in my module class but i am not getting any response in my callbacks.

Any help suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: HI have you resolved the issue I am facing the same issue, will you please help me how it done.